# I have a Jtable with a button in one of the columns and I want to access the value in the 1st column when I press the button

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, listener, jbutton

I Have a JTable with 3 columns: ID, Name and Operation. In this last column I have a button for every line ( I will post a printscreen ). When I press the button I want to access the value in the first column. I made a listener to the table and it works when I click on the table, but if I click in the button (that is in the 3rd column) it doesn't get the value ( I assume that it is because the click is not directly in the jtable).

How can I get the value when pressing the button?

Thank you

[print screen of the JTable function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxK7s.png)

The listener I made:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
          @Override
            public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    final JTable jTable= (JTable)e.getSource();
                    final int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                    final int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
                    final int valueInCell = (Integer)table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                    setSelectedID(valueInCell);
                    System.out.println("Selecionou: "+valueInCell);
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding regular `JButton`s to your table you could add your own custom `JButton`; which would implement `ActionListener` with the desired behavior when clicked (retrieve `data`), and at construction time would:

1. Receive (as an argument) and save the `data` that you want to reference in a field.
2. Registers itself as an `ActionListener`.

Such custom `JButton` would look like this:

```
public class DataButton<T> extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    private T data;

    public DataButton(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Selection: " + getData());
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```